# Need help to make this curl script multi links

Tags: php, html, curl

Here is the script it downloads files from url. The thing that I want is multi links like there should be three or more input url boxes in which user puts their links and the script downloads all the files. I don't want to press a button and another url box appear; that is not I want, I have already tried that. Or multi links; something like this where we can put links on each line:

[image]

```php
<?php
class Download {
    const URL_MAX_LENGTH=2000;

    // clean url
    protected function cleanUrl($url){
        if (isset($url)){
            if (!empty($url)){
                if(strlen($url)< self::URL_MAX_LENGTH){
                    return strip_tags($url);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //is url
    protected function isUrl($url){
        $url=$this->cleanUrl($url);
                if (isset($url)){
                    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED)){
                        return $url;
                    }
                }
    }


    //return extension 
    protected function returnExtension($url){
        if ($this->isUrl($url)){
            $end = end(preg_split("/[.]+/", $url));
            if (isset($end)){
                return $end;
            }
        }
    }

    // file download 
    public function downloadFile($url){
        if ($this->isUrl($url)){
        $extension = $this->returnExtension($url);
        if ($extension){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


        // directory where files should be downloaded
    $destination = "uploads/file.$extension";
        $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
        fputs($file, $return);
        if (fclose($file)) {
            echo "Successfully Download The File";
        }
        }
        }
    }

}
$obj = new Download();
if (isset($_POST['url'])) { $url = $_POST['url'];}

?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="url" maxlength="2000">
<input type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
<?php if (isset($url)) { $obj->downloadFile($url); }?>
```

Comment: Why don't you try [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)? break it on new line

Comment: could you please explain a little more as i am a newbe i m little in php curl (:

Answer (score 0):

Break string into array using `\n` as `delimiter`, you will get array of URLs. check below example to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

**Note:** Use `<textarea>`, if you use `input` and press `enter` then form will get submitted.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea type="text" name="url" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['url'])){
    $urls = explode("\n",$_POST['url']);
}
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo $url;
    //$obj->downloadFile($url);
}
?>
```

Comment: hmm i am having a little problem in the script the filename is not coming with the file its only file.extension and i cant be able to download multi files please help me out in my script.

Comment: also the file sizes of all files is 0kb downloaded

Comment: try to print array using `print_r($urls)`, check if you are getting proper urls ?